# 'Live Search' on Teams interprets everything as simple text search

Tags: bug, search, stack-overflow-for-teams

The new search dropdown in Stack Overflow for Teams, showing search results as you type, is very nice, but it's not really intelligent; when typing `user:me`, the result isn't one of my posts, but rather something that contains the words 'user' and 'me' as partial hits:

[image]

Similar things happen when searching for e.g. `score:10`.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica [here is an attempt](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1164150/attempt-to-list-suspended-users) but it's not 100% correct, you'd have to check the profiles yourself.

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post since Ham's response already addresses the specific concern here.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the feedback!

The live search is quite primitive. It only takes the entered search query as is and runs it against question titles within your teams. No special search operators are supported, nor does it search anywhere else but within question titles.

The regular site-search (simply hit enter) gives you the full search capabilities you're used to.

We want to improve the type-ahead search moving forward but have to carefully balance performance implications and relevance. The advanced search capabilities of our site-search are a blessing and a curse. It's great that it offers a lot of fine-grained control but the combination of all different sorts of search parameters and optimizations behind the scenes make predicting and tweaking search quality difficult.

We kept the type-ahead search simple for the first iteration. Once because we didn't want to keep the load on our elasticsearch servers in check but also because we wanted to take this as an opportunity to gradually tweak our search from a simple and predictable baseline.

Your feedback is helpful, it shows that we've got at least a problem with how we present information to the user. We'll take your feedback for our next iterations and see how we can make this less confusing.